# Is it possible to add memo checker to an XLM address?

Tags: memo

Is it possible to add memo checker to an XLM address so sending a deposit without memo to this address wouldn't be possible at all?
This feature exists for BNB, XRP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [SEP-0029: Account Memo Requirements](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0029.md).

SEP-0029 a standard way to define transaction memo requirements for incoming payments.

> To set up memo prerequisites for an account, the owner submits a transaction with a MANAGE_DATA operation that adds a data entry with the name config.memo_required (in lower case following SEP-18 notation) and value 1 (a single character string "1" - ASCII code 49 or Unicode U+0031).